# how to search in compound indexed document with partial part of the index in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi i have a schema with composed index to keep a unique combinaison of mail and organisation  in my MongoDB like this

```
let Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        organisation:{
            type:mongoose.ObjectId,
            required:true
            ref:'organisations'
        },
        mail:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        }
    },
    firstName:{ 
        type:String,
    },
    lastName:{
        type:String
    },
})
//some methods and statics here

const Contact = mongoose.model('contacts',Schema);
```

I would like to query all documents that match a specific organisation id without giving a mail ( for listing from organisation purpose )
I have read something about this

```
await Contact
   .find(
      {
         _id:{
            organisation:organisation,
            mail:{"$exists":true}
         }
      }
   )
```

but i get an empty result
so I try some regex

```
await Contact
   .find(
      {
         _id:{
            organisation:organisation,
            mail:{"$regex":"[^]*"}
         }
      }
   )
```

but i keep getting the same empty result
the only time I get result is when precising the exact mail of a document but its useless for listing all the mail of an organisation

Does anyone know what am i doing wrong ?
sorry i am kinda new at this NodeJS > Mongoose > MongoDB Stack

Comment: You need to use [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-and-condition). Eg `"_id.organisation"` and similar for the other field

Comment: Thank you so much it's working now ! I will post the full answer, thanks again ! the post about the "$exists" operator for compound id has misguided me

Comment: I forgot there is reputation here maybe do you wanna post the answer yourself to get credit or reputation point since its your solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem being encountered here is related to the semantics when a full nested document is specified in the query. Per [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document):

> Equality matches on the whole embedded document require an *exact* match of the specified `<value>` document, including the field order.

So the first query in the question is looking for a document whose `_id` value is exactly `{ organisation:organisation, mail:{"$exists":true} }` (with whatever value is present for the `organisation` variable at the time). I had to use a different field name due to [a restriction with the `$` in subfields of `_id`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field), but you can see a general example of the problem and semantics in [this playground demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4TC0OD2HlRp).

What you want instead is to use [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-and-condition).Specifically something like:

```
db.collection.find({
  "_id.organisation": 123,
  "_id.mail": {
    "$exists": true
  }
})
```

See the [playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fHmGxAsqZBa).